# How to filter items in QListWidget

Tags: pyqt5

I have the following QlistWidget:

```
self.myListWidget1 = QListWidget()    

os.chdir("./Downloads")
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
  QListWidgetItem(file, self.myListWidget1)
self.myListWidget1.sortItems()
```

How can I add a QLineEdit that is able to filter items in self.myListWidget1 by partial
string?

Comment: You can use the example presented as you seem to have or you could do it a much simpler and much more straight forward way by using a List to hold your data and using the QListView to handle just displaying the data.  I created a MUC (Minimal Usable Code) example that does this and I can either send it straight to you or I can drop it in Stack Chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need a separate list on which you will do the filtering and then display the filtered list in the QListWidget.

The most basic example could look like this:

```py
    self.myLineEdit = QLineEdit()
    self.myListWidget1 = QListWidget()
    self.listOfPdfs = [] # this will hold the complete list of files

    os.chdir("./Downloads")
    for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
        self.listOfPdfs.append(file) # fill the list
        QListWidgetItem(file, self.myListWidget1)

    # connect the signal textChanged to the filter function
    self.myLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.filterList)

def filterList(self, text):
    self.myListWidget1.clear() # clear the list widget
    for file on self.listOfPdfs:
       if text in file: # only add the line if it passes the filter
           QListWidgetItem(file, self.myListWidget1)
```

(note that I didn't check the validity of the code, minor modifications might be needed)

Comment: Are you sure about that first `self` argument in `filterList`?

Comment: I assumed the original code was a snippet of a class, therefore `filterList` should be its method.

Comment: @Papooch There is only drawback on the beginning, it should show all files, but it shows nothing. I'm trying to solve it.

Comment: @xralf you can invoke `filterList` manually upon startup with `text = ""`

Comment: @Papooch Even if it was, written like this `filterList` is a local function, so its first argument will actually be the text of the signal, and it will raise an exception since the function has two arguments. So, you either remove `self` or make `filterList` a method, with the correct indentation.

Comment: @musicamante I edited the connect call to reflect that, now it should be valid. Also what do you mean by a correct indentation?

Comment: @Papooch I sincerely hope that you know what indentation is. With your correction now it will raise an AttributeError, since `filterList` is *still* a local function, *not* a method, and `self` does not have any `filterList` attribute. I know that you didn't check its validity, but that's just the *elementary* python indentation rule.

Comment: @musicamante Of course I know what indentation is, that's why I am confused. Assume that all the code in my answer is indented by one level as it is the inside of a class, the code around could be put into the constructor or something. The answer is accepted, so I guess OP figured it out, feel free to suggest an edit if you will.

Comment: @Papooch Yes, it's understandable. What was most difficult for me, was the textChanged event and reaction to it.

Answer (score 4):

The currently accepted answer by Papooch is not very good unfortunately. The reason is that it will not keep the current row event if it remains withing filter criteria. You do not want to generate a new list. You actually want to hide items which are not withing filter criteria. Do it like this:

```
void ItemsListWidget::filterItems(QString filter)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < count(); ++row)
    {
        item(row)->setHidden(!item(row)->text().contains(filter, Qt::CaseInsensitive)); // you can leave out the case insensitivity if you do not want it
    }
}
```

(it is Qt/C++ code but I am pretty sure you can easily adapt it for Python)